# API - Authentication Route - Password in Header vs Body

Tags: api, express

I know the topic has a lot of dicsussion on StackOverflow however I can't seem to get a definitive answer:

If:

- I have an API.
- For an authentication (login and password) route I can use either GET or POST
- Then from what I've read, If using GET (params are passed in the header) and POST (through the body).

However which is more secure for sending that password - Header or Body?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use POST method with base 64 decoding (or others) instead of GET for authentication  purposes. POST is more secure protocol.